# Как преобразовать массив бит в строку?

Tags: python, кодировка

У меня есть строка из не печатных символов. Мне надо ее передать на сервер. Проблема в том, что в "сыром" виде стоку не передашь (в ней могут быть спец символы). Делаю `urlquote`. Но `urlquote` не работает с юникодом, и все не печатные символы заменяет, в следствии чего на сервер приходит искаженная строка. Как мне сделать так, чтобы на сервер приходила начальная строка?

Хочу сделать так: взять строку и преобразовать так, что новая строка будет содержать коды символов, например, новая строка может выглядеть так - `"\xfa\xdd\x99..."`. Вопрос в том, как получить такую строку? Пробовал пакет `struct.pack`, не вышло.

Добавлю. Изначальная задача стоит в передачи на сервер буффера байт, который я преобразую в строку и передаю в GET запросе. Возможно есть альтернативное решение.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`base64encode/base64decode`?

Comment: base64 вроде и создан был для таких случаев?

Comment: Да, клевая штука. Только одно но - у меня не python/python. Питон только на одной стороне. Как я понял на другой стороне используется другой кодек, тк получить идентичную строку на сервере я не могу. Может другие предложения?

Comment: вообще то base64 это сдандарт. А стандарты везде одинаковы, вне зависимости от языка программирования.

Comment: Насколько помню в base64 только с двумя символами могут быть проблемы. 63 и 64 символы. Но пайтон позволяет их задать вручную.

Comment: Если не сложно, поясните про 63 и 64 символа.

Comment: python -c 'import base64; print base64.b64encode("\xfa\xdd\x99...");'

Comment: Прочитайте английскую вики про base64. Там есть таблица сравнения стандартов.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте bad_line.encode('unicode-escape', 'replace')
Я не совсем уверен на счет ключа 'replace'. Нужно пробовать.